# Have WSL shell open to project directory in Windows Visual Studio Code

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a windows subsystem for Linux Installed on my computer and am using it as the integrated terminal on Visual Studio Code. Every time I open a terminal however, it opens in the root directory rather than the current project directory like other terminals do.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

I have tried messing with the `Cwd` of the integrated terminal settings but haven't had any luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I know that is very late for this answer, but for me it just worked.
I put exactly as above and it launched in my home directory (that is /mnt/d/Users/Adrian).

I have the user setup of VSC, 1.30.1 and launch it from the Desktop shortcut.
After I configured terminal as wsl I go as below:
If I open a cmd windows I can launch it with `code .` it will launch in Windows home directory.
If move to some other folder (e.g Documents) and launch it with `code .` the bash will launch to that folder.
Otherwise I can launch it with `code D:\Users\Adrian\Documents\VSC` and the bash terminal will launch in `\mnt\D\Users\Adrian\Documents\VSC`

Tested the change both via menu File->Preferences->Settings and with Ctrl+Shift+P (Command Pallete), Terminal: Default Shell.

Tried with bash and wsl.

Maybe you have some other bash installed in the path? (e.g. git bash or MinGW bash?)

Comment: Yeah, I finally got it working too after reinstalling VS Code. I ran into more trouble trying to get it to work with my React Native projects so gave up with the whole idea though. Thanks Adrian

Answer (score 2):

Try using `wsl.exe` as the command for shell.

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "wsl.exe"
```